# rails generate model references type

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I generated a couple models and it created the following migration files. In the 2nd migration you will see 2 references types. sub_configuration_id is a reference to the item_configurations_model. This is an optional reference (it can be NULL).

When I looked at ItemConfigurationOption model I noticed the following `belongs_to :sub_configuration_id`. This is not valid because belongs_to :sub_configuration_id is NOT a model. How should I reference the possible relationship for sub_configuration_id?

```
class ItemConfigurationOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item_configuration
  belongs_to :sub_configuration_id
end

class CreateItemConfigurations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :item_configurations do |t|
      t.references :item, index: true
      t.string :name
      t.string :description
      t.integer :type

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class CreateItemConfigurationOptions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :item_configuration_options do |t|
      t.references :item_configuration, index: true
      t.references :sub_configuration_id, index: true
      t.string :name
      t.string :value
      t.decimal :price

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change third line to :

```
belongs_to  :sub_configuration, :class_name => :ItemConfiguration, :foreign_key => :sub_configuration_id
```

With above syntax you can declare a relation to ItemConfiguration.
Then you can gen subconfiguration object with  sub_configuration method.

Comment: Got it! On a side note...What does the references data type actually mean/do? Is this appropriate in this case?